# Long.parselong numberformatexception

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app on the market, and received some errors pointing the same line. Thing is, I cannot determine what the error is, since I haven't met it in the emulator and a couple of phones. I tested it in the emulator for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi density, and for 2.1 and 4.0.3 also. I tried it out on phones with 2.2, 2.3.5 and 4.0.3.

This is the code and the error line:

```
   Log.i("REFRESH d1 | d2", d1 + "|" + d2); //null | null

 if ((d1 == null) && (d2 == null))
            {
                String dA = "";
                HotOrNot infod = new HotOrNot(Calllogs.this);
                infod.open();
                Cursor cursorA = infod.getAllTitles_DateLimit1("DESC");
                 if (cursorA.moveToFirst())
                 {
                 do{
                    dA = cursorA.getString(5);
                }while (cursorA.moveToNext());
                }

                d1= dA;
                infod.close();

                 String dB = "";
                HotOrNot infodd = new HotOrNot(Calllogs.this);
                infodd.open();
                Cursor cursorB = infodd.getAllTitles_DateLimit1("ASC");
                if (cursorB.moveToFirst())
                {
                   do{
                    dB = cursorB.getString(5);
                }while (cursorB.moveToNext());
                }

                d2=dB;
                infodd.close();
            }
            else
            {

            }


            Log.i("REFRESH2 d1 | d2", d1 + "|" + d2);  // 1339789896078|1339790132268


                Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal1.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(d1)); //NumberFormatException
                cal1.set(cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal1.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);
                GlobalVars.setD1(String.valueOf(cal1.getTimeInMillis()));



                Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal2.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(d2));
                cal2.set(cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal2.get(Calendar.DATE), 23, 59, 59);
                GlobalVars.setD2(String.valueOf(cal2.getTimeInMillis()));
```

The error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException:  at
>   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:337) at
>   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:311) at
>   com.b2creative.b2callstats.Calllogs$14.run(Calllogs.java:1416) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

d1 and d2 are declared strings and the data coming from the database is string is well (I store dates as strings (like longs: 1339789896078)). Apart from that the user has no calls in the calllog and thus the database is empty, I can think of no other reason to cause this exception.

Maybe `long.decode` is better?

I was thinking it can be that the user has no sdcard, but it runs smoothly on 2 phones without sd card.
What can be the root of the problem?

Comment: Why don't you catch the exception.. perhaps its empty?

Comment: What do you mean? All I can do now is to check if there are any records in the table, because if it is empty, d1 and d2 is null

Comment: is this not possible d1 is null but d2 is not null?

Comment: can d1 or d2 not have value this ""? it is not null but not a long as well